# Mysql & Express, how to get my data and create nested array

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I have a table of users from my Mysql DB and i need to output a nested one, for my datatable to work properly but i don't know from where to start i use mysql, express, vue-cli, node.js .. Im a padawan learner on vue and node js. All good advices are welcome. thanks!

Here's my output:

```
"users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "Fido",
            "name": "Alex Cristianssss",
            "avatar": "aaa.jpg",
            "email": "rudra@mail.com",
            "role": "admin",
            "status": "active",
            "is_verified": "true",
            "registered": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "last_login": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "progress": "44%",
            "inf_id": 1,
            "dob": "25 September 2020",
            "city": "",
            "mobile": "3333",
            "website": "http://daaaaaa.ro",
            "lang_known": "Romana",
            "gender": "male",
            "twitter": "https://twitter.com/aaaaa",
            "facebook": "https://twitter.com/adoptionism744",
            "instagram": "https://twitter.com/adoptionism744",
            "github": "https://twitter.com/adoptionism744k",
            "codepen": "https://twitter.com/adoptionism744",
            "slack": "@adoptionism744"
        }
    ]
```

And i need to output like this:

```
"users": [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "username": "Fido",
            "avatar": aaa.jpg,
            "name": "Alex Cristianssss",
            "email": "fido@da.net",
            "mobile": "3333",
            "role": "admin",
            "status": "active",
            "is_verified": "true",
            "dob": "25 September 2020",
            "gender": "male",
            "website": "http:\/\/daaaaaa.ro",
            "languages_known": "Romana",
            "contact_options": [
                "email",
                "message",
                "phone"
            ],
            "location": {
                "add_line_1": "A-65, Belvedere Streets",
                "add_line_2": "",
                "post_code": "1868",
                "city": "New York",
                "state": "New York",
                "country": "United States"
            },
            "social_links": {
                "twitter": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/aaaaa",
                "facebook": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/adoptionism744",
                "instagram": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/adoptionism744",
                "github": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/adoptionism744k",
                "codepen": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/adoptionism744",
                "slack": "@adoptionism744"
            }
        }
```

Js code:

```
exports.getUserList = function (req, res) {
  console.log('get user list')
        
  const queryString = 'SELECT * FROM users u JOIN informatii_users b ON u.id = b.uid AND b.uid = u.id'
        
  connection.query(queryString, function (err, rows) {    
    //console.log(rows)
    if (err) {
      console.log('in Error')
      const resultData = JSON.stringify({'success': false, 'data': 'Problem in fetch data'})
      res.send(resultData)
    } else if (rows.length > 0) {
      const resultData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({'error': false, 'users': rows}))
      res.send(resultData)
    } else {
      const resultData = JSON.stringify({'success': false, 'data': 'No Data available'})
      res.send(resultData)
    }
  })
}

exports.getUser = function (req, res) {
  console.log('get user info') 
  console.log('ID:', req.params.userId)
  const queryString = `SELECT * FROM users u JOIN informatii_users b ON u.id = ${req.params.userId} AND b.uid = ${req.params.userId}`
        
  connection.query(queryString, function (err, rows) {    
   
    if (rows.length <= 0) { 
      console.log('error', `User not found with id = ${req.params.userId}`)
      const resultData = JSON.stringify({'success': false, 'data': 'Problem in fetch data'})
      res.send(resultData)
    } else if (rows.length > 0) {
      const resultData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({'error': false, 'users': rows}))
      res.send(resultData)
    } else {
      const resultData = JSON.stringify({'success': false, 'data': 'No Data available'})
      res.send(resultData)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: You can modify rows array using `array.map()` method

Comment: Can you show me how based on my code ? im new with this.. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by `array.map()` function:

```js
let rows = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "Fido",
            "name": "Alex Cristianssss",
            "avatar": "aaa.jpg",
            "email": "rudra@mail.com",
            "role": "admin",
            "status": "active",
            "is_verified": "true",
            "registered": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "last_login": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "progress": "44%",
            "inf_id": 1,
            "dob": "25 September 2020",
            "city": "",
            "mobile": "3333",
            "website": "http://daaaaaa.ro",
            "lang_known": "Romana",
            "gender": "male",
            "twitter": "https://twitter.com/aaaaa",
            "facebook": "https://twitter.com/adoptionism744",
            "instagram": "https://twitter.com/adoptionism744",
            "github": "https://twitter.com/adoptionism744k",
            "codepen": "https://twitter.com/adoptionism744",
            "slack": "@adoptionism744"
        }
    ];
    
    let result = rows.map(el => {
      el.contact_options = {
      email: el.email || null,
      message: el.message || null,
      phone: el.phone || null
    };
    delete el.email, el.message, el.phone;
    return el;
});

console.log(result);
```

Above example only set `contact_options` element.

Comment: Nice! Thank you!